# What is Crawl Speed?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

On page 182 of the PHB, there is a section titled **Climbing, Swimming, and Crawling** that contains no details about crawling. In the section, it says:

> While climbing or swimming, each foot of movement costs 1 extra foot
>   (2 extra feet in difficult terrain), unless a creature has a climbing
>   or swimming speed.

Does this apply to crawling speed as well?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is answered on page 191 of the PHB:

> ## Being Prone
>
> [...] To move while prone, you must **crawl** or use magic such as teleportation. Every foot of movement while crawling costs 1 extra foot. Crawling 1 foot in difficult terrain, therefore, costs 3 feet of movement.

Answer (score 13):

The rules for crawling are on page 191. Which is to say, in the chapter on Combat, under the Being Prone section.

> To
>   move
>   while
>   prone,
>   you
>   must
>   crawl
>   or
>   use
>   magic
>   such
>   as
>   teleportation.
>   Every
>   foot
>   of
>   movement
>   while
>   crawling
>   costs
>   1
>   extra
>   foot.
>   Crawling
>   1
>   foot
>   in
>   difficult
>   terrain,
>   therefore,
>   costs
>   3
>   feet
>   of
>   movement.

Why the section you're looking at includes Crawling in the title, I don't know.

Comment: But it's right there.  Maybe this was one of those 'it's related so leave it there' editorial decisions.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast My guess would be that it was there, and then they decided it should go under combat, and they forgot to change the title when they moved it.

Answer (score 4):

The rules for it are on page 191, under the "Being Prone"section:

> To move while Prone, you must crawl or use magic such as teleportation. Every foot of movement while crawling costs 1 extra foot